# Different animations when entering different routes in Angular1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

I have two types of angular routes and I want there to be one animation when entering one type and another animation when entering another type.

The different types of routes are "left sidebar" and "full page" so I'm going to need to add a class to  of either "left-sidebar" or "full-page" and write CSS to add different animations.

I tried doing something like this:

```
<div id="ng-view"></div>
...

.when('/sidebar-route', {
    templateUrl: ..,
    controller : ..,
    resolve    : {
        animation: [function() {
            // add class to ng-view:
            document.getElementById('ng_view_div').add('left-sidebar');
        }],
```

This didn't seem to work because document.getElementById() doesn't work on the ng-view div for some reason (it returns null).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
<div ng-view="{{ routeType }}"></div>

....

app.controller('SidebarCtrl', [function() { 
   $scope.routeType = 'sidebar';
}];

app.controller('FullPageCtrl', [function() { 
   $scope.routeType = 'full-page';
}];
```